# Paste data from clipboard in tabulator table with button

Tags: tabulator

I want to use a button on my website that should paste the data from the clipboard in the tabulator table. So instead of the key press CTRL + V on the table, the user can also click the button. I thought to implement this by just setting focus to the  table and stimulating the CTRL + V keypress, but this doens't work... Can somebody help me to improve my code? Or maybe there is a much more simple solutions than stimulating the key press..
My code:

```
$("#tabulator_table").tabulator({
                    data:tableData,
                    history:true,
                    clipboard:true,
                    clipboardPasteAction:"replace",
                    layout:"fitColumns",
                    height:"400px",
                    columns:[
                        {title:"index", editor:true},
                        {title:"Naam",  editor:true},
                        {title:"number", sorter:"number"}
                    ],
                });
```

AND

```
        $("#paste-button").on("click", function(){
            document.getElementById("tabulator_table").focus();         
            var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
            e.which = 86;       
            e.ctrlkey = true;     // control key pressed
            $('#tabulator_table').trigger(e);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Im afraid it is impossible to programatically trigger a paste, it can only be done through the standard methods such as ctrl+v and using the standard context menu.

This is a browser security feature that all browsers implement to prevent websites stealing peoples data, imagine if you had a password in your clipboard and a website used some eJavaScript to steal it :(